# How to escape a SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE span in Android EditText on pressing enter?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I was creating a text editor in android from scratch (as I wanted it to be lightweight and have full control over it). I am using a `QuoteSpan` or/and a `BulletSpan` on an `EditText` with `SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE`/`SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE`, so that the bullets and quoteSpan continue on next line as the user presses enter on the EditText.

The end result is as expected, the bullets appear on the next line as the user presses the enter key. But now it turns into an endless loop where on pressing enter the bullet appears on next line.

How can I escape this endless loop? For example, in other text editors, it escapes out by pressing enter twice?

```java
// this code is inside a bulletBtn.onClickListener();
// bodyEt is the EditText;
start = bodyEt.getSelectionStart();
end = bodyEt.getSelectionEnd();
bodyEt.getText().setSpan(new BulletSpan(), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

Actual result:

> • 1
>    • 2
>    • 3
>    • 
>    • 
>    • 
>    • 
>    • lorem ipsum solor dit

Pressing enter doesn't escape the bullet span on the result above.

Expected result:

> • 1
>    • 2
>    • 3
>   
>   Lorem ipsum solor dit

The result above escaped the bullet span.
Must escape the bullet span on pressing enter twice.

Comment: try by checking double enter click using nested if for ENTER event if double click then remove bullet

Comment: @DEEPANSHU tried it but it doesn't work, also  KeyEvent.ENTER isn't working on some of my android devices!